# How to implement a generic abstract function?

Tags: c#

The problem is a little more complex, than the question looks. I have an abstract class. And i want it to have an abstract function, but with return type and param type of the class, that implements it.

So I want to have something like:

```
public abstract class Class
{
    public abstract T DoSomething(T variable) where T : Class;
}
```

so i can have another class like

```
public class Class1 : Class
{
    public override Class1 DoSomething(Class1 variable) {...}
}
```

is this possible?

Comment: You might be interested in this proposal (seems to be exactly what you wished was possible): https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11773

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need a generic parameter constrained to the base type.

```
public abstract class MyClass<T> where T : MyClass<T>
{
    public abstract T DoSomething(T variable);
}
```

and

```
public class MyDerivedClass : MyClass<MyDerivedClass>
{
    public override MyDerivedClass DoSomething(MyDerivedClass variable)
    { ... }
}
```

This is all somewhat akin to a [self-referencing generic pattern](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/simonince/2008/06/12/generics-the-self-referencing-generics-pattern/)

Comment: that's not possible because you need to make the where clause of a generic base Type too. 
public abstract class myCalss<T> where T : MyClass<T1> or something. at least thats what VS tells me

Comment: Oh! But i just discovered that you can use the dynamic type in the where clause too so it would be 
public abstract class MyClass<T> where T : MyClass<T>
i don't know if this still does what's needed but at least there's noe exception anymore

Comment: @KyoshiroKokujouObscuritas - sorry you're right. I updated the answer

Comment: i found that answer too but without that where clause, and i wanted it to just be able to be used from derived types. I tried your version first but that didn't work out since i had to specify a type, that confused me, but if a generic type is possible in where clause too, it's all good ^_^

Comment: I don't follow "and i wanted it to just be able to be used from derived types". Is there something you're still missing? Does the added link help?

Comment: nono it's okay. the answers I found didn't use the where clause so you could do something like this:

public class Class3 : Base<Class2>

Comment: basically that'd be possible even now, but at least Class2 musst now inherit something from base... is there even a more strict restriction?

Comment: I'm still not sure I follow what the problem is.

Comment: Simple. With this restriction it's possible to pass another type than the implementing type. i want to prevent that.
as i told: class Class3 : Class<Class2> is possible with that current syntax, when Class2 implements Class too. But i want Class3 : Class<Class3> the only possible implementation

Comment: Ah right, no there is not a generic constrain that can do that.

Comment: i'll add it to my question maybe someone has an idea if that's somehow possible... i mean you always want your code to be robust against such unplanned abusing :)

Comment: You might be better to ask a *different* question - or, please do not invalidate this answer by putting this code in the question. (ie, feel free to put this code in a new question and ask how to better constrain it)

Comment: oh welll... okay ^_^